# Error Bootstrapping - Illegal instruction

Tags: ruby, linux, openssl, chef-infra

I am trying to bootstrap a server sing CHEF tool, the target machine is "CentOS 5.8"

But I get this error. Note: It doesn't happen on all the servers.

> Starting the first Chef Client run...
>       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so: [BUG] Illegal instruction at 0x002b5ac1b082a5
>       ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

```
-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0019 p:-41548458 s:0097 e:000096 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0095 e:000094 CFUNC  :require
c:0017 p:0132 s:0091 e:000090 METHOD /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0016 p:0008 s:0080 e:000079 TOP    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.rb:13 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0078 e:000077 CFUNC  :require
c:0014 p:0132 s:0074 e:000073 METHOD /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0013 p:0098 s:0063 e:000062 TOP    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/config.rb:34 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0061 e:000060 CFUNC  :require
c:0011 p:0132 s:0057 e:000056 METHOD /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0010 p:0048 s:0046 e:000045 TOP    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/config.rb:30 [FINISH]
c:0009 p:---- s:0044 e:000043 CFUNC  :require
c:0008 p:0132 s:0040 e:000039 METHOD /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0007 p:0053 s:0029 e:000028 TOP    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef.rb:24 [FINISH]
c:0006 p:---- s:0027 e:000026 CFUNC  :require
c:0005 p:0132 s:0023 e:000022 METHOD /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55
c:0004 p:0051 s:0012 e:000011 TOP    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/bin/chef-client:23 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0624 s:0006 E:001360 EVAL   /usr/bin/chef-client:57 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:002470 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `<main>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:57:in `load'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/bin/chef-client:23:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/config.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/config.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/openssl.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
RIP: 0x00002b5ac1b082a5 RBP: 0x0000000013f8c5b0 RSP: 0x00007fff325c11a8
RAX: 0x00000000000306e4 RBX: 0x0000000000000800 RCX: 0x0000000000000000
RDX: 0x000000004f8bfbff RDI: 0x00002b5ac1c2a4d5 RSI: 0x00007fff325c4fb8
R8: 0x0000000013ffdf20  R9: 0x00000000ffba2223 R10: 0x000000004f8bfbff
R11: 0x000000000000000d R12: 0x00000000139619c0 R13: 0x00000000139619c0
R14: 0x00007fff325c4fb8 R15: 0x0000000000000005 EFL: 0x0000000000010246

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3 [0x2b5abbd56775]
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3 [0x2b5abbd571f7]
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3 [0x2b5abbc34220]
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3 [0x2b5abbce234a]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x2b5abc051ca0]
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0(fips_openssl_ia32_cpuid+0x145) [0x2b5ac1b082a5]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /usr/bin/chef-client

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 thread.rb
    2 rational.so
    3 complex.so
    4 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
    5 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
    6 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/unicode_normalize.rb
    7 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb
    8 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    9 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    10 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    11 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    12 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/version.rb
    13 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
    14 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/platform.rb
    15 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
    16 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
    17 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/util/list.rb
    18 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
    19 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb
    20 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    21 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
    22 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb
    23 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
    24 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb
    25 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
    26 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
    27 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/version.rb
    28 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/nil_argument.rb
    29 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/mash.rb
    30 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/windows.rb
    31 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/logger.rb
    32 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/exceptions.rb
    33 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.7/lib/mixlib/shellout/exceptions.rb
    34 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/exceptions.rb
    35 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/logger.rb
    36 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/prettyprint.rb
    37 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/pp.rb
    38 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/monologger.rb
    39 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-log-1.7.1/lib/mixlib/log/version.rb
    40 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
    41 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/date.rb
    42 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/time.rb
    43 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-log-1.7.1/lib/mixlib/log/formatter.rb
    44 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-log-1.7.1/lib/mixlib/log.rb
    45 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/syslog.so
    46 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/syslog-logger-1.6.8/lib/syslog-formatter.rb
    47 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/syslog-logger-1.6.8/lib/syslog-logger.rb
    48 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/mixin/unformatter.rb
    49 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/log/syslog.rb
    50 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/event_dispatch/base.rb
    51 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/event_loggers/base.rb
    52 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/platform/query_helpers.rb
    53 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/log/winevt.rb
    54 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.21.3/lib/chef/log.rb
    55 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-config-2.2.4/lib/mixlib/config/version.rb
    56 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-config-2.2.4/lib/mixlib/config/configurable.rb
    57 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-config-2.2.4/lib/mixlib/config/unknown_config_option_error.rb
    58 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-config-2.2.4/lib/mixlib/config/reopened_config_context_with_configurable_error.rb
    59 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-config-2.2.4/lib/mixlib/config/reopened_configurable_with_config_context_error.rb
    60 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-config-2.2.4/lib/mixlib/config.rb
    61 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
    62 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/pathname.rb
    63 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/fips.rb
    64 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/path_helper.rb
    65 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fuzzyurl-0.9.0/lib/fuzzyurl/version.rb
    66 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fuzzyurl-0.9.0/lib/fuzzyurl/fields.rb
    67 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fuzzyurl-0.9.0/lib/fuzzyurl/protocols.rb
    68 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fuzzyurl-0.9.0/lib/fuzzyurl/match.rb
    69 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fuzzyurl-0.9.0/lib/fuzzyurl/strings.rb
    70 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/fuzzyurl-0.9.0/lib/fuzzyurl.rb
    71 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-config-12.21.3/lib/chef-config/mixin/fuzzy_hostname_matcher.rb
    72 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
    73 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb
    74 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tmpdir.rb
    75 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
    76 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.7/lib/mixlib/shellout/unix.rb
    77 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mixlib-shellout-2.2.7/lib/mixlib/shellout.rb
    78 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb
    79 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb
    80 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/common.rb
    81 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/generic.rb
    82 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/ftp.rb
    83 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/http.rb
    84 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/https.rb
    85 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/ldap.rb
    86 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/ldaps.rb
    87 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/mailto.rb
    88 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri.rb
    89 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/version.rb
    90 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb
    91 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/idna.rb
    92 /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/addressable-2.4.0/lib/addressable/uri.rb

* Process memory map:

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2325                               /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fd:01 2325                               /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
137f7000-1416f000 rw-p 137f7000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2b5abb9b0000-2b5abb9cc000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 131404                     /lib64/ld-2.5.so
2b5abb9cc000-2b5abb9ce000 rw-p 2b5abb9cc000 00:00 0
2b5abbbcc000-2b5abbbcd000 r--p 0001c000 fd:01 131404                     /lib64/ld-2.5.so
2b5abbbcd000-2b5abbbce000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:01 131404                     /lib64/ld-2.5.so
2b5abbbce000-2b5abbe22000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2636                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3.0
2b5abbe22000-2b5abc022000 ---p 00254000 fd:01 2636                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3.0
2b5abc022000-2b5abc02a000 rw-p 00254000 fd:01 2636                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.3.0
2b5abc02a000-2b5abc03b000 rw-p 2b5abc02a000 00:00 0
2b5abc043000-2b5abc059000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 130401                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
2b5abc059000-2b5abc259000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 130401                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
2b5abc259000-2b5abc25a000 r--p 00016000 fd:01 130401                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
2b5abc25a000-2b5abc25b000 rw-p 00017000 fd:01 130401                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
2b5abc25b000-2b5abc25f000 rw-p 2b5abc25b000 00:00 0
2b5abc25f000-2b5abc266000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 130632                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
2b5abc266000-2b5abc466000 ---p 00007000 fd:01 130632                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
2b5abc466000-2b5abc467000 r--p 00007000 fd:01 130632                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
2b5abc467000-2b5abc468000 rw-p 00008000 fd:01 130632                     /lib64/librt-2.5.so
2b5abc468000-2b5abc469000 rw-p 2b5abc468000 00:00 0
2b5abc469000-2b5abc46b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 130408                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
2b5abc46b000-2b5abc66b000 ---p 00002000 fd:01 130408                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
2b5abc66b000-2b5abc66c000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 130408                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
2b5abc66c000-2b5abc66d000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 130408                     /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
2b5abc66d000-2b5abc676000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 130369                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
2b5abc676000-2b5abc875000 ---p 00009000 fd:01 130369                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
2b5abc875000-2b5abc876000 r--p 00008000 fd:01 130369                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
2b5abc876000-2b5abc877000 rw-p 00009000 fd:01 130369                     /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
2b5abc877000-2b5abc8a5000 rw-p 2b5abc877000 00:00 0
2b5abc8a5000-2b5abc927000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 130643                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b5abc927000-2b5abcb26000 ---p 00082000 fd:01 130643                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b5abcb26000-2b5abcb27000 r--p 00081000 fd:01 130643                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b5abcb27000-2b5abcb28000 rw-p 00082000 fd:01 130643                     /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b5abcb28000-2b5abcb29000 rw-p 2b5abcb28000 00:00 0
2b5abcb29000-2b5abcc78000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 130499                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
2b5abcc78000-2b5abce78000 ---p 0014f000 fd:01 130499                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
2b5abce78000-2b5abce7c000 r--p 0014f000 fd:01 130499                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
2b5abce7c000-2b5abce7d000 rw-p 00153000 fd:01 130499                     /lib64/libc-2.5.so
2b5abce7d000-2b5abce84000 rw-p 2b5abce7d000 00:00 0
2b5abce84000-2b5ac0452000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 402051                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
2b5ac0452000-2b5ac0553000 rw-p 2b5ac0452000 00:00 0
2b5ac0553000-2b5ac0554000 ---p 2b5ac0553000 00:00 0
2b5ac0554000-2b5ac0557000 rw-p 2b5ac0554000 00:00 0
2b5ac0557000-2b5ac0559000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3502                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
2b5ac0559000-2b5ac0758000 ---p 00002000 fd:01 3502                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
2b5ac0758000-2b5ac0759000 rw-p 00001000 fd:01 3502                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
2b5ac0759000-2b5ac075b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3545                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
2b5ac075b000-2b5ac095b000 ---p 00002000 fd:01 3545                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
2b5ac095b000-2b5ac095c000 rw-p 00002000 fd:01 3545                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
2b5ac095c000-2b5ac0962000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3585                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
2b5ac0962000-2b5ac0b62000 ---p 00006000 fd:01 3585                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
2b5ac0b62000-2b5ac0b63000 rw-p 00006000 fd:01 3585                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
2b5ac0b63000-2b5ac0b99000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3490                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
2b5ac0b99000-2b5ac0d98000 ---p 00036000 fd:01 3490                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
2b5ac0d98000-2b5ac0d9a000 rw-p 00035000 fd:01 3490                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
2b5ac0d9a000-2b5ac0d9b000 rw-p 2b5ac0d9a000 00:00 0
2b5ac0d9b000-2b5ac0d9e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3587                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/syslog.so
2b5ac0d9e000-2b5ac0f9d000 ---p 00003000 fd:01 3587                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/syslog.so
2b5ac0f9d000-2b5ac0f9e000 rw-p 00002000 fd:01 3587                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/syslog.so
2b5ac0f9e000-2b5ac0fa4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3574                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
2b5ac0fa4000-2b5ac11a3000 ---p 00006000 fd:01 3574                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
2b5ac11a3000-2b5ac11a4000 rw-p 00005000 fd:01 3574                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
2b5ac11a4000-2b5ac11a9000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3556                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
2b5ac11a9000-2b5ac13a8000 ---p 00005000 fd:01 3556                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
2b5ac13a8000-2b5ac13a9000 rw-p 00004000 fd:01 3556                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/etc.so
2b5ac13a9000-2b5ac13aa000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3557                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
2b5ac13aa000-2b5ac15a9000 ---p 00001000 fd:01 3557                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
2b5ac15a9000-2b5ac15aa000 rw-p 00000000 fd:01 3557                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
2b5ac15aa000-2b5ac15f6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 3573                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
2b5ac15f6000-2b5ac17f6000 ---p 0004c000 fd:01 3573                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
2b5ac17f6000-2b5ac17fa000 rw-p 0004c000 fd:01 3573                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
2b5ac17fa000-2b5ac1859000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2639                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
2b5ac1859000-2b5ac1a59000 ---p 0005f000 fd:01 2639                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
2b5ac1a59000-2b5ac1a63000 rw-p 0005f000 fd:01 2639                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
2b5ac1a63000-2b5ac1cad000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2604                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2b5ac1cad000-2b5ac1ead000 ---p 0024a000 fd:01 2604                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2b5ac1ead000-2b5ac1ed9000 rw-p 0024a000 fd:01 2604                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
2b5ac1ed9000-2b5ac1edd000 rw-p 2b5ac1ed9000 00:00 0
2b5ac1edd000-2b5ac1ef1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2658                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libz.so.1.2.11
2b5ac1ef1000-2b5ac20f1000 ---p 00014000 fd:01 2658                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libz.so.1.2.11
2b5ac20f1000-2b5ac20f2000 rw-p 00014000 fd:01 2658                       /opt/chef/embedded/lib/libz.so.1.2.11
2b5ac20f2000-2b5ac20f5000 r--s 00000000 fd:01 2325                       /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby
2b5ac20fa000-2b5ac2107000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 140090                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
2b5ac2107000-2b5ac2307000 ---p 0000d000 fd:01 140090                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
2b5ac2307000-2b5ac2308000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:01 140090                     /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
2b5ac2308000-2b5ac232c000 r--s 00000000 fd:01 130401                     /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
2b5ac232c000-2b5ac2333000 r--s 00000000 fd:01 791674                     /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
2b5ac2333000-2b5ac2334000 rw-p 2b5ac2333000 00:00 0
7fff31bc8000-7fff325c7000 rw-p 7fffff5ff000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7fff325fd000-7fff32600000 r-xp 7fff325fd000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Answer (score 0):

We do not offer installers for CentOS 5 anymore but for Chef 12 it's possible you got the one for either the wrong CPU arch or CentOS 6 or 7.

Comment: I have some servers with the exact same versions and they work, same image from digital ocean.
How do I check if the package is suitable for CPU?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest upgrading your operating systems to 5.11 with whatever the latest patches are and rebooting.  It is possible that we've only built and tested on 5.11 and those packages are broken on 5.9.  And like coderanger suggests, validate that you're getting the correct chef package for your system and architecture.  It needs to be something like:

```
chef-12.21.31-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

For 64-bit RHEL5.  For 32-bit RHEL5 it should be:

```
chef-12.21.31-1.el5.i386.rpm
```

If that doesn't work there's not a lot to be done.  Chef-12 is getting EOL'd, RHEL5 is getting EOL'd and Ruby 2.3 is getting EOL'd.

Comment: I have some servers with the exact same versions and they work, same image from digital ocean, some works and some don't, and the package is "chef-12.21.31-1.el5.x86_64.rpm"